# Twitter-Bootstrap modal and django form

Tags: django, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-views

I'd like to show `last_item` in a Twitter-Bootstrap modal after django form submission, however I don't know how to handle the modal. I tried the form button suggested in [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), but it doesn't process the form data. What do I have to do?

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Submit</button>
```

#### views.py

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            request.session['name'] = name
            mm = MyModel.objects.create(name=name)
            mm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = MyModelForm()
    args = {}
    args['last_item'] = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('pk').reverse()[0]
    args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'form.html', args)
```

#### form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST" id="" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="modal" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModal2Label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModal2Label">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Last item: {{ last_item }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: "doesn't process the form data" ? What happens exactly ? If in doubt, use ipdb.

Comment: When I use `<button>Submit</button>` the modal doesn't appear and the form data is inserted in server. `last_item` shows the inserted data. When I use `<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Submit</button>` the modal appears, but the form data is not inserted in server. `last_item` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L222) like bootstrap calls `event.preventDefault()` on click, which prevents the form from being submited.

You should [bind your own event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) on this button and [close the modal programaticaly](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

It could look like:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
})
```

I did not test this code but it should be a good start.

Comment: I tried your code with different events (`show`, `shown`, `hide` and `hidden`). In all of them the server data is updated. However, with hide events the modal doesn't appear, and with show events the modal appears for one second with old data. I'd like to show the modal with the updated data until close button click. How can I do this?
When I try only `$('#myModal2').modal();` the modal works, but opens when I load the page.

Comment: You should call .modal() in the $.ajax success callback.